# Grouping data in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hy,

I have the following problem. I have 2 datasets, one containing data of the following structure:

```
A1 B2 C1 D1
A1 B2 C1 D3
A3 B1 C2 D2
etc
```

and the other one containing values for these objects:

```
A1=x
B2=y
C1=z
D1=q
etc
```

How can I group the data so than I can have A1=x B2=y C1=z D1=q  in one place, to compute them ?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the second dataset small enough to fit in memory on a datanode?

Comment: let's say yes. you say to save it into a list?

Comment: More likely a map of some sort, but yeah.  You can distribute the file through the `DistributedCache` and read it with your mappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2nd dataset is small, you can put it into Distributed Cache.

You can read the 1st data set line by line in the mapper & then use input from the distributed cache to obtain values, and then emit a key-value pair  like , <"A1=x B2=y C1=z D1=q", 1>

Comment: Thank you guys! My actual dataset actualy contains ~1.200.000 lines of values: 30-40 characters by line. Don't know if is too large or not to fit in memory.

Comment: that should not be too large, you can give it a shot